# How can I validate input length, but ignore alphas?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input that will have input between 3-5 alphanumeric characters.

I want to validate that the user input between 3-5 characters:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,5}$/
```

But, I want to ignore any alpha characters on form submission, not strip them.

So an input value of `"RS032"` stays that way in the input on form submission, but the form only actually returns `"032"`

Comment: "ignore the alphas" — what exactly ignoring means here? Give us an example of your desired input/output.

Comment: I believe your question is how to have the submitted form value equal `032` but for the value to appear to stay the same after the form is technically submitted. If this is the case, I believe you have a misconception - what appears in the field after a submit is typically dependent upon the server (in which case we'd need to know what your server side language is), unless you're using an AJAX submit... (???)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a little shy of details, but I'm guessing you want to validate everything in the field except letters. So, if the input is `abc1d2e3fgh` and your requirement is 3 digits, you want that to pass.

For a very basic requirement like this, you can intersperse optional `[A-Za-z]*?` sets between the other required characters. So, for the 3-numbers requirement, you could use

`[A-Za-z]*?\d[A-Za-z]*?\d[A-Za-z]*?\d[A-Za-z]*?`

This requires 3 digits (`\d`), and allows any number of letters before, between, or after those digits.

If you need to use match/capture groups, instead of just verifying match/no-match this won't work.

Unless you have a very basic requirement, there is no way that I know of to achieve this with a single RegEx. You'll likely need to assign the string to another variable, strip the letters, and then validate. By assigning to another variable, you can leave the input in place.

---

### Update in response to question edit:

It sounds like you *do* want to strip the letters, only you want to do it in the backend. I think that is exactly what you should do, instead of conflating that with validation.

If you really want to do the work client-side, you could use an additional, hidden field, that you update via Javascript when the "source" text changes. On the server you can ignore the "source" field and instead use the "stripped" one.

Comment: That pattern could be shortened to: `([A-Za-z]*?\d){3,}` which would make it easier to maintain.

Comment: +1 for the interpretation and the solution, but you should anchor it at both ends, and you don't need to make the quantifiers non-greedy.  @Marcus, same thing applies to your regex, and you forgot to account for letters after the last digit.  EDIT: ...or did you change the hypothetical to three **or more** digits?

Comment: @AlanMoore it will match 3 or more. Since it doesn't use any anchors the optional letters after can be skipped :)

Comment: @Marcus and Alan, you guys are correct, of course. The hypothetical could have been stronger to demonstrate that this can quickly become rather onerous.

Comment: +1 this edit (`Update in response...` seems to answer the intent of the question better, and is essentially the solution I would have offered.